# Embed markdown file in Rhino shiny framework

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown

I have a markdown file which I want to include in the shiny app, which can be done by following for a simple shiny framework.

```
column(8,align = "left",includeMarkdown("my_markdown.Rmd"))
```

By I was trying the same with the Rhino framework, but it is not working.

I am expecting to show the html version of the R markdown in the shiny app using the Rhino framework.

Comment: Is your markdown in  www directory

Comment: Yes it is in the www folder. I also tried with "www/my_markdown.Rmd" did not work for me.